# After processing a deep link inside the app, redirect user back to the browser

Tags: android, navigation, react-native

React Native [Ejected Expo Project]

I'm trying to redirect a user back to the browser after processing a deep link inside the Android app. Is there any common method for switching a user back to *one app under* (previously active/opened) the currently running up?

For example:

1. After activating deep link from Opera Browser, my app starts
2. I'm processing that request inside the app
3. I'm moving my app to the background and bringing back Opera to the foreground

I was playing around with React Native Linking but it opens either default browser or Google Chrome, depending on a custom URL Scheme. Because I couldn't find a way to open other browsers the same way I open Chrome (googlechrome://), my last hope is to find a way to switch back to a browser that triggered my deep link.

[Trusona](https://www.trusona.com/) & [Freja eID](https://frejaeid.com/en/home/) are apps doing exactly what I want. After authorization attempt approval on your mobile device, you're redirected back (you can even see, that transition between app and browser is in a "back manner") to the original browser from which you started authorization process.

Thank you!